# Терминология настольных игр

Tags: выбор-слов

Вопрос в 2-х частях про настольные игры.

1. Вот что нагуглилось в процессе исследования терминологии:

   - *плитки* -- это плоские штуки, которые выкладывают, чтобы играть *на* них; то есть после того, как положили плитку, она становится частью игрового поля и не двигается до конца игры.
   - *фишки* -- это плоские штуки, которыми манипулируют в процессе игры.
   - *миплы* -- это фигурки животных или людей, которыми пользуются, как фишками.
   - *Карты/карточки*, *жетоны* и *токены* представляют из себя некую ценность и ими обмениваются или приобретают. Не совсем понятно, чем они отличаются друг от друга, кроме внешнего вида -- *карты/карточки* плоские и из картона.
   - *кости* - это кубики, необязательно кубической формы, которые бросают, чтобы внести элемент случайности в игру.

Правильно ли это?

2. Теперь вопрос на засыпку:
   Чем играют в *Маджонг* -- пасьянс, в который играют в одиночку?
   Интернет разделился между плитками, фишками и костями.
   Я сильно подозреваю здесь влияние перевода с английского. То есть ясно, что эта терминология формируется под влиянием английского, но ведь Маджонг был раньше!
   И чем же в него играли в до-интернетовский период?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Игра маджонг похожа скорее на домино, чем на карты. И, кстати, в домино тоже используются кости, так что "кости" не обязательно имеют кубическую форму.

Есть замечательная статья на Википедии про маджонг, где, в частности, говорится, что [пасьянс Маджонг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3#.D0.9F.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.8C.D1.8F.D0.BD.D1.81_.D0.9C.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B6.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B3) - это вариант игры в Маджонг для одного человека (кстати, для домино тоже есть пасьянсы).

Действительно, маджонг в России известен, по крайней мере с 1926 года. Большим любителем этой игры был Владимир Маяковский. Лев Кассиль так пишет об игре Маяковского в маджонг:

> Сняв пиджак, засунув большой палец одной руки в пройму жилета, он другой крепко ставит **кости на стол**, и четыре ветра ма-джонга скрещиваются над его головой.
>   *— Л. Кассиль, «Маяковский — сам: очерк жизни и работы поэта»*

Кроме того есть официальное русское издание [правил спортивного маджонга](http://www.mahjong.ru/files/mjru0909.pdf), принятых в 2006 году Международной Организацией Маджонга, в которой игральные фишки называются кости.

Правила игры в [пасьянс Маджонг](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/mahjong-titans-how-to#1TC=windows-7) (Mahjong Titans) на сайте Микрософт:

> В начале каждой игры на доске 144 **кости**, которые разложены одним из шести различных способов: Черепаха, Дракон, Кошка, Башня, Краб или Паук.

А вот в версии Gnome Games (для Линукс), судя по [скриншоту из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Games#/media/File:Mahjongg_%28GNOME_Games_2.32.1%29_ru.png), кости называют "фишки".

[image: Фишек: 144]

---

Что касается первой части вопроса, то да, есть общие (общеупотребимые) названия для предметов игрового инвентаря которые используют носители языка если не знают как эти предметы называются согласно правилам игры. И, кстати, "миплы", "плитки" и "токены" в этот общий список не входят.

НО! В каждой конкретной настольной игре могут быть свои названия для предметов, не входящие в "общую" классификацию. Так в шахматах на доске стоят **фигуры** (а не фишки и не "миплы"), в го - камни (не фишки и не костяшки). Так что в маджонге тоже может быть для игровых предметов два названия - одно, которое используют люди не знакомые с игрой (фишки, "штучки", "карточки", "квадратики"), и другое, которое используют сами игроки, и которое отражено в правилах игры ("кости"). Разницу между этими названиями можно прочувствовать, если вспомнить как профессиональные шахматисты относятся к фразам и названиям типа "тура" (а не "ладья"), "офицер" (а не "слон"), "лошадь" (а не "конь"), "королева" (а не "ферзь") и т.д.

Comment: в том-то и дело, что на Википедии есть отдельная статья про [маджонг-пасьянс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%29). Фишки в ней упоминаются 12 раз, а кости - 4!

Comment: user244413 ну не поменяется же название инвентаря от того, играете ли вы один или вдвоем???

Comment: @user244413 Очевидно писал статью человек, играющий в пасьянс маджонг на компьютере. На экране действительно разница между фишкой и костяшкой непринципиальна - это небольшая прямоугольная (почти квадратная) "штучка". Вполне подходит под определение "фишки". Но если играть в реальный Маджонг, я думаю что ощущение что это "фишка" сразу пропадет. Думаю ключевым здесь является то что "пасьянс" это "маджонг для одного". Точно так же как пасьянс для домино - это "домино для одного", и обычный пасьянс - это "карточная игра для одного". Предметы не меняют своих названий от того как ими играешь.

Comment: Aкtemix, эта разница и в реале непринципиальна. Я вот вспоминаю, такое ощущение, что костью (костяшкой) называют любую игровую фишку, если на ней нанесено что-то отличительное (число очков, картинка, рисунок). Поэтому в го, шахматах  и т.д. - фишки. В домино, маджонге, китайских шахматах - костяшки, которые и фишки тоже. Название "кости" идет от лошадиных костей, которые бросали как жребий (отсюда же и само слово жребий - жеребьевка).  А вот карты, карточки - не фишки. И не кости поэтому. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду ту игру, которая сидит в любом пакете Виндовс, то в ней играют костями.

Только разве Маджонг -- пасьянс не разные игры?

Comment: Что с чем разные? Про пакет не знаю.

Comment: behemothus, в Виндовс есть игра Маджонг. А пасьянс - эта игра в карты. Я поэтому спросил,разве это не разные игры.

Comment: Пасьянс - это головоломка. С картами, костями, фишками... С чем угодно.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81 Вики дает как обобщенное значение от игры в карты, но я даже в этом сомневаюсь. Ибо вообще не вижу причин как-то выделять карточные пасьянсы из общей массы. Игра в 15, солитер (не карточный), бирюльки... - ну чем не пасьянсы? Маджонг - типичный пасьянс.

Comment: Да, я прочитал статью на Вики. Маджонг, оказывается, тоже можно отнести к карточным играм.

Comment: "Маджонг, оказывается, тоже можно отнести к карточным играм" - ?????

Comment: Пасьянсы могут представлять собой не только привычную всем раскладку обычных игральных карт. Например, знаменитый Маджонг – это все тот же пасьянс. Однако в игре для него задействованы уже несколько иные элементы. Это карточки или таблички особой формы с изображениями и символам

Comment: Ну а причем тут ***карточные*** игры?

Comment: А в том, что кости также называются картами. Это тоже своего рода карты, выложенные на игровом столе . Карточная игра не в прямом смысле этого слова.

Comment: Не вижу ни малейших причин называть костяшки или фишки картами. Да и зачем? Зачем плодить сущности? Да меня и вполне устраивает версия вики, что пасьянс - любая тактическая головоломка для одного человека. Вы солитер (не карточный) видели? Тоже пасьянс. Но уж никак не карточный. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%91%D1%80_%28%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%29

Comment: Ну я не знаю, я никогда настольный маджонг не играл. Я привел информацию с интернета.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду цитату, то нет - и еще раз нет. Маджонг - игра **не карточная**. О том и спорим. Это игра с костяшками. Костяшки - не карты. Вы противоречите своей же цитате.

Comment: Я не противоречу. Я лишь сказал, что в компьютерном маджонге фигуры называются костяшками. А в цитате написано: "Это карточки или таблички особой формы с изображениями и символам..." Видимо имеется в виду настольная игра. Я никогда не играл настольный маджонг и утверждаю, что цитаты - истина в последней инстанции.